# Evaluation criteria of classifiers (test classification rate and training time)

Tags: classification, train

Does test classification rate and training time the best evaluation criteria for a classifier!
Basically I have used the training time and test classification rate as a criteria to evaluate my classifier ( as in  many papers, many studies they used training  test CR)

Is there anyone could explain  why test CR and training time are the most used?
Once we are asked to justify why these evaluation criteria, what a good answer should be? Honstly it starts to be a habit ( as in all papers I  read) we asked how long the classifer does take? and the % of correct answer.. But I need more logical answers ( more explained...)

Comment: Ive never seen anyone evaluate the performance of a model based on the training time. Perhaps you are reading about deep learning in particular, which are expensive to train?

Comment: @MatthewDrury thank you for your feedback, am reading about incremental feature learning ( and am coparing between two algorithms the conventional version the basic one and the incremental version . so a comparaison between two algorithms! it is not logical to use traning time as an evaluation criteria !